# Navigation bar Searchbar Space Is not Hiding in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

[image: Navigationbar with SearchBar]

[image]

HI i have implemented Searchbar in Navigationbar and

Hiding Navigationbar Progamatically but the space is not removing
PLease help how can i remove the space of searchbar hiding space

```
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


    search.searchResultsUpdater = self
    search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
    search.searchBar.placeholder = "search..."
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.navigationItem.searchController = search
```

for Hiding the SearchBar

```
search.searchBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: Can you please show how your code looks like ?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Added My code  whatever i have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding it won't be enough because it is still the `navigationItem` `searchController`, so you need to set it to `nil`

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
```

and later restore it if you want, simple as that.